# Multi step form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Theres a multi smtp form I found [online](http://phpflow.com/php/multi-step-form-using-php-bootstrap-jquery/). However the next and previous buttons are embedded into each `fieldset` and I would like them to be outside of the`fieldset` so they can be used for all the sets. Not just one.

And for the last one I'd `.show()` the submit button. As well as hide the previous button for the very first one.

Can this be done?

---

```
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">

<input type="button" name="next" class="next" value="Next">
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

<input type="button"name="previous" class="previous" value="Previous">
<input type="button" name="next" class="next" value="Next">
</fieldset>


<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">

<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous" value="Previous">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var current = 1,current_step,next_step,steps;

  steps = $("fieldset").length;

  $(".next").click(function(){

    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().next();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();

    setProgressBar(++current);
  });



  $(".previous").click(function(){

    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();

    setProgressBar(--current);
  });

  setProgressBar(current);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the `fieldsets` and the current position.

Then, wrapping them in `jQuery` calls everything is easy. See this example, based on your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 0,
    $form = $("form"),
    $steps = $form.find("fieldset"),
    numSteps = $steps.length;

  function setProgressBar(pos) {
    console.log("Step: " + pos);
  }

  function checkButtons() {
    if (current <= 0) {
      $(".prev").hide();
    } else {
      $(".prev").show();
    }

    if (current >= numSteps - 1) {
      $(".next").hide();
      $(".submit").show();
    } else {
      $(".next").show();
      $(".submit").hide();
    }
  }

  $(".next").click(function() {
    $($steps[current]).hide();
    $($steps[++current]).show();
    setProgressBar(current);

    checkButtons();
  });

  $(".prev").click(function() {
    $($steps[current]).hide();
    $($steps[--current]).show();
    setProgressBar(current);

    checkButtons();
  });

  checkButtons();
  setProgressBar(current);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
  </fieldset>
</form>

<input type="button" style="display:none" name="prev" class="prev" value="Previous">
<input type="button" style="display:none" name="next" class="next" value="Next">
<input type="submit" style="display:none" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
```

You also need to take care of the visibility of the buttons, which is what the `checkButtons` function is for. I am sure more elegant approaches are possible, but this one works.

Also note the `display: none` styles on the elements which are hidden at start.